# unable to View a page on my website but can View it in preview through Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

in the hamburger menu of our website, i created a Yoga Video Course Page via wordpress and it was working fine. I looked this morning and can see it in Wordpress and can even edit it and see it on the preview. However when i try to view it on our website th screen appears Black.
Any suggestions would be grateful?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open the inspect element and look if the elements are displayed as required. The issue might be due to several reasons. You need to investigate further and find a solution. Also look at the network tab on inspect element to make sure there are not 500 internal server errors. Also set the `wp_debug=true` on `config.php` to provide more error info. Also try to activate another theme and see if the page is being rendered properly.